# Maximum speed of a particle given velocity function in terms of vectors

Tags: calculus, vectors, kinematics

Find the maximum speed of a particle whose velocity, $\mathbf v$ m/s at time t seconds is given by: $$v=2\mathbf isin(t)+\mathbf jcos(t)+3\mathbf k, t\ge0$$

How do I solve this? I tried differentiating and equating to zero but I don't know if it's a valid approach here and if it is, how to take it from there.

Comment: What do you mean by $\sin(t\hat i)$?

Comment: There's no such thing as $\sin$ or $\cos$ of a vector. I guess that there's a typo.

Comment: Isn't it : $v=2sin(t)\mathbf i+cos(t)\mathbf j+3\mathbf k$ ?

Comment: They didn't use brackets in the textbook so I assumed that the sine and cosine are of the whole expression i.e. $sin(t\mathbf i)$ when I guess now it should be $sin(t)\mathbf i$.

Comment: @nicomezi - Yeah, the notation was a bit ambiguous.

Comment: But I still don't know how to solve it, could anyone help? I edited the question.

Comment: Considering that you have a scalar times a vector, the notation isn't ambiguous at all. The argument of $\sin$ is a scalar, not a vector, so it could only mean one thing. If they were both scalar so, then it would be ambiguous.

Comment: You're right, I meant ambiguous to me because I started learning vectors yesterday and I wasn't so obvious to me that a vector can't be an argument of a trigonometric function. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Speed is the magnitude of the velocity. So if the velocity is
$$v(t) =(2\sin t,\cos t, 3)$$ then the speed is
$$f(t)=|v(t)|=\sqrt{4\sin^2 t +\cos^2 t + 9}=\sqrt{10+3\sin^2 t}$$
using the facts that $|(a,b,c)|^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$ and $\sin^2 t+\cos^2 t=1$.

Now you have a real-valued function to maximize on $[0,\infty)$, which is a Calculus I problem.

Answer (score 5):

$$v=2\sin(t)\mathbf i+\cos(t)\mathbf j+3\mathbf k, t\ge0$$

First find the speed, which is the norm of $v$:

$|v(t)| = \sqrt{4\sin^2 t + \cos^2 t + 9} = \sqrt{3\sin^2 t + 10}$

You now need to maximise that. It's not that difficult. First note that the square root is a monotonic, strictly increasing function. Then note that $\sin^2 t$ has a maximum value of $1$. This immediately gives the max. speed as $\sqrt {13}$

Answer (score 4):

No, you have messed up the derivative.

**First of all**, you should have written the velocity as 
$$v=2\sin(t)\mathbf {\hat i}+\cos(t)\mathbf {\hat j}+3\mathbf {\hat k}$$ 
according to the conventional notation and not $$v=2\sin(t\mathbf i)+\cos(t\mathbf j)+3\mathbf k$$ where you seem to take the $\sin$ or $\cos$ of a vector.

**Secondly**, the derivative of a vector of the form $$\vec r=a\mathbf {\hat i}+b\mathbf {\hat j}+c\mathbf {\hat k}$$ is generally expressed as $$\frac{d\vec r}{dt}=\frac{da}{dt}\mathbf {\hat i}+\frac{db}{dt}\mathbf {\hat j}+\frac{dc}{dt}\mathbf {\hat k}$$
A vector is *not like* a constant, you just do not differentiate *it*.

So as you can now calculate, 
$$\frac{dv}{dt}=2\cos (t)\mathbf {\hat i}-\sin (t)\mathbf {\hat j}+0\cdot \mathbf {\hat k}$$
or $$\frac{dv}{dt}=2\cos (t)\mathbf {\hat i}-\sin (t)\mathbf {\hat j}$$

**Last but not the least**, the question asks for the maximum *speed* and not the maximum *velocity*.

And speed $= |v| = \sqrt{4\sin^2(t)+\cos^2(t)+3^2} = \sqrt{3\sin^2t+10}$

Now maximise $|v|$ by calculating and equating $\frac{d|v|}{dt}=0$.

Hope this helps you.